# Android can not remove button

Tags: android, button, view, onclick, buttonclick

I am trying to remove a button when the button itself is tapped, I am trying the following:

```
View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tagsView.removeView(button);
        }
    };
}
```

This code is working, but when I add the following line of code:

```
editText.setText(button.getText());
```

The code stops working and the button does not get removed. I add it like so:

```
View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(button.getText());
            tagsView.removeView(button);
        }
    };
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

use this in your OnClick method

`button.setVisibility(view.GONE);`

Your code will look like this

```
View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
return new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setText(button.getText());
       button.setVisibility(view.GONE); 
      }
   };
}
```

Or Try this

```
  Button mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn_id);
  mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         mybtn.setVisibility(view.GONE); // or  (view.INVISIBLE)

        }
    });
```

Comment: comment your code and try this snippet I've updated in my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, something like **deejay** proposed would work just fine. If want the button to hide, call `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. However, if you are trying to dismiss it completely from the view hierarchy, call `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Comment: @chris d Weird. Please clarify what your intentions are or post a minimal working example. I've never seen this setup of an OnClickListener. Are you sure you wired this up correctly? Why are you setting the text of an editable field to the text of a button? 
And (probably not leading to a solution for this one) I have experienced trouble with setText() if I don't include a String like this: "whatever string ", so my workaround is setText("" + someVariable).

Answer (score 1):

just set button visibility to false

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)` comes to mind but if it doesn't work you should look one level above for the source of the bug. Maybe you don't **set OnClickListener you created to the button** and hence nothing happens?